# Get-PSDrive not giving me the share I have a drive letter mapped to

Tags: powershell

When I dump the return of what Get-PSDrive returns, root will show the share I mapped drive letter Z to. But not when I explicitly access it , like $sl[10].Root , it just gives me the drive letter again.

I need to get at the share, to know if its mapped already or not.

[image]

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: The name is a hash and order may not be same as displayed.   So try : $sl.z.Root

Comment: While running `pwsh` 7 on Ubuntu, `$output[4].Root` returns `/tmp/`, which is the `Root` of a drive named 'Temp'.

Comment: It's both PowerShell and PowerShell ISE that comes with windows 11.   Its 5.1.2261.1778 in both. 

Both  $s[10].Name.gettype() and $s[10].Root.gettype() return string as dat type.

Comment: Found it, there is another member, not in the docs for PSDriveInfo , its DisplayRoot. $s[10].DisplayRoot 
\\server\shares\dirs1\dirs2\dir3

Comment: @deetle, you should consider adding your previous comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Building on your own discovery:

- The **[`System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo)** instances that **[`Get-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive)** outputs have ***two* properties relating to the root path** of a (file-system) drive:

  - **`DisplayRoot`** is **only populated for *system-known* drives *mapped to network shares***, and reports the network share in ***UNC format***, which is what you're looking for (*system-known* drives are those visible to *all* processes,<sup>[1]</sup> not just to *PowerShell* commands).

    - Somewhat confusingly, what the default *table formatting* of `Get-PSDrive` shows as the `Root` column (property) is actually a *calculated* value that situationally returns either the `DisplayRoot` or the true `Root` property (discussed below):
      `if($_.DisplayRoot -ne $null) { $_.DisplayRoot } else { $_.Root }`<sup>[2]</sup>

      - By contrast, if you pipe to `Format-List` only the true `Root` property values are shown.
    - To **see and contrast the true property values**, specify the property names explicitly, via the (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter:

      ```
       Get-PSDrive | Format-Table Name, Root, DisplayRoot
      ```
    - To *programmatically*, extract the *calculated* value (not just for display), you can use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) (or just use the `if` statement in a `ForEach-Object` script block to extract the property value alone):

      ```
       Get-PSDrive | 
         Select-Object Name, @{ 
           Name='TrueRoot'; 
           Expression={ if ($_.DisplayRoot) { $_.DisplayRoot } else { $_.Root } } 
         }
      ```
  - **`Root`**, which for file-system drives is *always* populated, is expressed as follows:

    - For ***system-known* drive definitions** (i.e. those visible to *all* processes, not just to *PowerShell* commands) as the ***drive letter-based* path of the drive's root directory** (e.g, `C:\` and `Z:\`)  which comprise:

      - *Local* drives
      - *System-known drive mappings* to network shares, established via *system* features such as File Explorer and `net use`, as well as via [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) *if* the `-Persistent` switch was used *and* the call was either made from the *global scope* or a `-Scope Global` argument was passed.<sup>[3]</sup>  To learn their *UNC* root path, you must use the `DisplayRoot` property (see below).
    - For ***PowerShell-only* drive definitions**, established with [`New-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive) (without `-Persistent`), it is the **root path *as defined*** (as passed to the `-Root` parameter), which means:

      - For **PowerShell-only drives mapped to *local* directories**, you'll see that **directory's full, *system-native* path** (i.e., expressed in terms of a drive known to the system):

        - E.g., for the automatically defined `Temp:` PowerShell drive, it is something like `C:\Users\jdoe\Temp\`
      - For **PowerShell-only drives mapped to *network shares***, you'll see the ***UNC* path** of that share.

        - E.g., for a drive `Z:` established with
          `New-PSDrive Z FileSystem -Root \\server\shares\dir1`, you'll see `\\server\shares\dir1`

---

<sup>[1] *Local* drives are seen by processes running as *any* user, whereas *mapped drives* (drives mapped to *network shares*) are *user-specific* and are by default not even seen by a given user's *elevated* (run-as-admin) processes.</sup>

<sup>[2] You can discover this as follows:

`((Get-FormatData System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo).FormatViewDefinition | Select -First 1).Control.Rows.Columns`</sup>

<sup>[3] These requirements ensure that the drive mapping is equivalent to one established with `net use ... /persistent:yes`, and are documented as such. However, that `-Persistent` *alone* isn't enough is an obvious pitfall. Sadly, fixing this problem was decided against - see [GitHub issue #15752](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15752).</sup>